# Why does man complain about a function defined in .profile?

Tags: bash, man, profile

I use Bash 5.1.8.  Running `man` shows the manual page but with the following errors

```bsh
man ps

sh: bat: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: bat: line 10: ` *.?(ba)sh)'
sh: error importing function definition for `bat'
```

I think some shell (`sh`) is finding Bashisms obnoxious.  These errors vanish if I remove Bash-isms like the following from `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
    function bat {
        # lines snipped for brevity

        case "$f" in
            *.rs      ) opt_syntax="--syntax=rust";;
            *.?(ba)sh ) opt_syntax="--syntax=shellscript";;
            *.?(m)m   ) opt_syntax="--syntax=objc";;
        esac

        # lines snipped for brevity
    }
    export -f bat
```

I'm sure `.bashrc` itself has no problems, as I see no errors or warnings when Bash starts.  Debugging further I noticed `.profile` sourcing `.bashrc`

```bsh
# source Bash customizations
[ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ] && [ -r "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] && . "${HOME}/.bashrc"
```

Here's how my `~/.bashrc` starts

```bsh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return
```

Questions:

1. Why does `man` have to source `.profile` just before starting?
2. Despite two checks why is the aforementioned code parsed by a non-Bash shell?

   1. Check in `.profile` to not source `.bashrc` when it's not Bash
   2. Check in `.bashrc` to stop further processing when non-interactive

From @muru's comments I realize that I should NOT have Bashisms in a function that's exported since there's a risk of it being imported by a non-Bash shell.  A question that still remains: **why `man` calls `sh`?**.

Comment: "error importing function definition"? Is the function exported?

Comment: Yes, I do `export -f bat`.  Aah... so it can't have Bash-isms after all?!

Comment: Bash invoked as `sh`  will try to import function definitions, but some behaviour will change. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Comment: Removing the `export` does solve the issue.  Will read about Bash's POSIX mode; thanks @muru!  However, I still don't see why `.profile` is sourced by `man`.

Comment: I don't see `.profile` being sourced. If it was, the error would have mentioned the file being sourced. I think it's only the exported functions being imported by `sh`. Not sure why `man` is running `sh`, though. Maybe for paging?

Comment: Aah... you're right.  Actually it's not sourcing `.profile`; verified by putting a debug-echo statement.  Your diagnosis is correct: _I think it's only the exported functions being imported by `sh`._  You can add this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`man` is not reading your `~/.profile` but it will run `sh` to interpret some command lines (or to interpret `nroff` which at least on my system is a `sh` script wrapper to `groff`), and on your system `sh` happens to be `bash`, which *imports* functions exported by `bash`'s `export -f` (in variables named `BASH_FUNC_funcname%%` since shellshock), even when running as `sh`.

Here, you're exporting a function whose syntax depends on the `extglob` option. So, when `sh` (`bash` in `sh` mode) starts and imports all the exported functions, it fails to parse it as `extglob` is not an options that is enabled by default (in `sh` mode or not).

IOW, exporting a function means that function will be available in all `bash` invocations and all `sh` invocations on systems where `sh` is implemented with `bash`. So you need to be careful that the syntax in those functions be compatibles with both `bash` and `sh`-as-`bash` in their default settings, or avoid exported functions altogether as the code in those functions will be parsed even if the functions will never end up being invoked.

See:

```
$ env 'BASH_FUNC_f%%=() { case x in ?(x)) echo x; esac; }' bash -O extglob -c f
x
$ env 'BASH_FUNC_f%%=() { case x in ?(x)) echo x; esac; }' bash -c f
bash: f: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: f: line 0: `f () { case x in ?(x)) echo x; esac; }'
bash: error importing function definition for `f'
bash: line 1: f: command not found
```

If your function needs a non-default option that affects syntax parsing like `extglob`, you can define it as:

```
f() (
  shopt -s extglob
  eval '
    function body here
  '
)
export -f f
```

Here running the code in a subshell for the option to only be set during the execution of the function (`bash`, contrary to `zsh` or `ksh` has no local scope for options (other than the ones set with `set` in recent versions)),  and using `eval` delays the parsing until the function is invoked and the `extglob` option set.

Here, you could also do:

```
f() (
  shopt -s extglob
  pattern='*.?(ba)sh'
  case ... in
    ($pattern)...
  esac
)
```

Though, you could also do:

```
f() {
  case ... in
    (*.sh | *.bash) ...
  esac
}
```

Which is standard `sh` syntax that doesn't require `extglob`.

Comment: When `sh`-as-`bash` is run, how'd it treat `shopt -s extglob` inside `f()`?

Comment: @legends2k, from a *syntax* point of view, `shopt -s extglob` is a simple command with 3 arguments, there's no shell that would fail to parse that command. If an `sh` invocation ended up *running* that `f` function, it would invoke the `shopt` command. Only `bash` imports those functions exported in `BASH_FUNC_f%%` variables, and `shopt` is a builtin of that shell, so it would not have any trouble running it even if running in posix mode.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Do you believe it is a good idea to use opening case label brackets in example code? Opening brackets for case labels are permitted by POSIX, but no corectly working shell implementation needs them.

Comment: @schily, yes, I much prefer that syntax, it also helps for `vi` `%` matching. The asymmetric ones should be relegated to history IMO.

Answer (score 12):

Don't export functions, especially functions that require a non-default bash configuration.

Exported functions are a bash feature, so they don't affect other shells. But they affect all invocations of bash. Your function requires the `extglob` option to be enabled, otherwise not only does running the function fail, but even *parsing* the function definition fails. And when the function is exported, bash parses the function definition before it starts executing anything.

The `sh` shell is the glue code for unix systems. It's not just for interactive use, it's also used a lot behind the scenes. Programs invoke `sh` for many purposes. `man` invokes several companion programs, and any of them might invoke a shell. For example, the usual implementation of `nroff` (which is the main command to convert a man page's source code into text formatted on a terminal) on Linux is a shell script that invokes `groff` (the GNU implementation of `nroff`) with a few options to make it compatible with a traditional `nroff`. This invokes `sh`, which depending on the distribution might be dash, bash (or, far more rarely on Linux, some other implementation).

For interactive use, bash loads `.bashrc`, so there's no point in having functions in the environment: put their definition in `.bashrc`, or a file sourced from `.bashrc`. For your own scripts, put function definitions in a file of your choice (not `.profile` or `.bashrc` themselves, because they contain things that should not be executed for every script) and put a `source` or `.` command in the script. There's very little to be gained by exporting function definitions: since you control the scripts where they're used, you can make them source the place where the definition is located. And it can't possibly work if the function can't be parsed by bash in its default settings.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I've used `groff` years ago for writing man pages myself, never knew it's calling `sh` behind the scenes until today.  I agree with the admonition of not exporting functions but the flip side is to do it without Bashisms, I believe.  Other than not gaining much, are there any other reasons to avoid exporting functions?

Comment: @legends2k Bashisms aren't a problem since only bash will import the functions anyway. The problem is using a non-default bash feature that affects the parser.

Comment: I understood that part (of avoiding non-default bash options in exported functions), but my comment/question was on why avoid function exporting in general?  I get it that there's little to gain from exporting them, but are there other reasons?